# STEP Geometry Transformations

Tags: transformation, step

Lately I've been building a STEP (iso 10303-21) importer as a necessary requirement for a project I've been working on. So far, I've got the geometry right (so far as I can tell), but the orientation and position is only right on 60%-80%, which leads me to think that I'm not properly handling `AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D`s.

Right now the way that I parse the file starts at the `SHAPE_REPRESENTATION_RELATIONSHIP`, and process the two shape representations that it contains. For most BREP shapes, it's just a simple 'cascade' effect, until I reach the `ADVANCED_FACE` where all 2D (edge) data is processed, before being passed into the `ELEMENTARY_SURFACE`, which constructs the shape based on that data.

Currently I'm using the transformation of all of the 2D edge geometry, but Ignoring the transformation of the `ELEMENTARY_SURFACE`. I'm also ignoring all of the `SHAPE_REPRESENTATION` transformations, but using them to eventually 'get' to and use the `ITEM_TRANSFORMATION`s.

I should also mention that (except for the 2D edge data), transformations are all added up, and applied in the end. To add a transformation, I convert the axes to a rotation matrix (via [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884979/derive-a-quaternion-from-three-axis) question), multiply them together, and then simply add the transformations.

**Update1**

I've changed the way that `AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D`s are added together by removing the translation addition. Now I'm just Adding the rotations, and using the 2nd's translation, and seem to be getting oddly more accurate results.